# Cygwin issue with expect - spawn id exp64 not open

Tags: cygwin, tcl, expect

I have a problem, if I run a TCL/expect script from cygwin.
When I'm getting the 64th session, I got the following error(debug output):

```
spawn ssh useri@1.1.1.1
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {8972}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp64) match glob pattern "unsuccessful login"? no
"Can't ping useri@1.1.1.1! Quitting."? no
"refused"? no
"Bad IP address"? no
"computer name"? no
"Usage of telnet deprecated, instead use"? no
"Invalid input detected at"? no
"timed out"? no
"o route to host"? no
"closed"? no
"ermission denied"? no
"estination unreachable"? no
"imeout expired"? no
"(NO/YES)"? no
"continue connecting"? no
"Username: useri"? no
"ser:"? no
"sername:"? no
"assword:"? no

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp64) match glob pattern "useri@server%"? no
"useri@server:*%"? no
"useri@server>"? no
"useri@server"? no
"server "? no
"server\r"? no
"server>"? no
"server"? no

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp64) match glob pattern "@asd"? no
expect: read eof
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp64"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) ""
exp_i_parse_states: : spawn id exp64 not open: spawn id exp64 not open
    while executing
"expect {
      # Special cases, switch to different login
      -i $sid "unsuccessful login"  { exp_continue }
      -i $sid "Can't ping $Username@$Ho..."
    (procedure "connecthor" line 5)
    invoked from within
"connecthor $Servername($i) $Server($i) $Serveruser($i) $Serverpass($i) $Option $sid $Enablepass"
    (procedure "dialin" line 44)
    invoked from within
"dialin $Routername $L_user"
    ("-(checker)" arm line 31)
    invoked from within
"switch -regexp -nocase -- [lindex $argv 0] \
  -(initpass) {
    puts "\r\rThis is the initial password manager module of to script."
    puts "WARNIN..."
    (file "/usr/bin/to" line 366)
```

The script is working fine, doing it's job until it reaches the session exp64. I've also tried to run the script under Ubuntu natively instead of Cygwin. It was working fine, without any error.

I'm experiencing this issue with other scripts as well.
I've already tried to re-install Cygwin, same issue appeared.

Do you maybe have an idea what could it be?

---

In the meantime:

Just wrote a minimal script, SSHing to a Cisco router, send a command, and exit out. It does the job in an endless loop, so I can log the $spawn_id in the meantime:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set i 1
while {1} {
    spawn ssh username@1.1.1.1
    set sid $spawn_id
    expect "assword:"
    send "Start123\r"
    expect "Router"
    send "show ip int brief\r"
    while {1} {
        expect {
            "Router" {send "exit\r"}
            eof {break}
        }
    }
    puts "*** Loop is running: $i, spawn_id is: $sid ***"
    incr i
}
```

I get the same error with this as well:

```
*** Loop is running: 60, spawn_id is: exp63 ***
spawn ssh username@1.1.1.1
send: spawn id exp64 not open
```

Comment: Mind pasting your code?

Comment: Just tried spawning (`spawn bash; send exit\r; expect eof`) 10000 bash processes in cygwin (on windows 7). No errors.

Comment: Thank you for checking. I think this is something with the ssh on windows7. I've tried many things, use the close command, exit out completely with expect eof, but non of them was working. However I do not have multiple SSH connections opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you did not  `wait` the exited ssh process. Without the `wait`, an exited ssh process would be showed as `defunct` which is still consuming the `PID` and maybe some `FDs`. You can try like this:

```
    while {1} {
        expect {
            "Router" {send "exit\r"}
->          eof { wait -nowait; break }
        }
    }
    puts "*** Loop is running: $i, spawn_id is: $sid ***"
    incr i
```

or

```
    while {1} {
        expect {
            "Router" {send "exit\r"}
            eof { break }
        }
    }
->  wait -nowait
    puts "*** Loop is running: $i, spawn_id is: $sid ***"
    incr i
```

Comment: Million thanks, you solved my issue!!! I've tried wait -nowait already, but put that into wrong place. I see the fault now.

Answer (score 2):

There's a limit on the number of simultaneous expect sessions that can be maintained. That limit varies by OS, and is (on some platforms at least) a **global limit**, not a process-local limit. Though since you're on Windows, there might also be per-process limits that you're hitting; I'm not entirely sure (though 64 sounds exactly like one of those). In any case, it sounds like you're hitting resource exhaustion.

Are you remembering to `close` once you're finished interacting with a particular host? If you've got lots of old expect sessions about in the process, you'll be leaking a pretty precious pool of resources.

Comment: Thank you! I used "close -i $sid; wait" commands for solving the issue. Now the number of opened SSH sessions is not increasing anymore, however I'm getting the same issue.
Could it be that somehow there are still opened sessions in the background?